# Aligning the elemnts within a button HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with 1. an icon and 2. some normal text.
The problem is that the icon and the text are on different heights WITHIN the button. I thought something like this would work:

```
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">
                <div class="row">
                    <i class="material-icons md-48">hourglass_full</i>
                    Some Text
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
```

it does work, but the w3c validator tells me, that

> "Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context."

How are you supposed to align the elements within a button then? I didnt find a solution :S

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of bootstrap classes, specifically flexbox

- `d-flex` will make the button a flex box
- `align-items-center` will center flex items vertically

Take a look

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="p-5">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg d-flex align-items-center m-auto">
   <i class="material-icons md-48">hourglass_full</i>
   <span class="ml-2">Some Text</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly how I wanted it to! The flex box is in general very useful I used it in some other parts now as well!

Comment: Glad it helped :) .. flex box is a powerful property !